# Function that extracts value from one array depending on the value of another array

Tags: python, numpy

my data consists from two numpy arrays 'a' and 'b':

```
In: a # numpy array, type int64
Out: array([4, 3, 1, ..., 3, 2, 3])

In: b # numpy array, type float 64
Out: 
array([[-0.07],
       [ 0.08],
       [-0.53],
       ..., 
       [ 0.25],
       [ 0.52],
       [ 0.11]])
```

Both arrays are the same length and I want to create a function that returns an array of values from 'b' depending on the value from array 'a'. I tried the function below, but it doesn't do the job properly.

```
def my_func(a,b):
    result = []
    for i in b:
        for z in a:
            if z==5:
                result.append(i)
    return np.asarray(result)
```

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do a little clearer? You say you want an array with values from b depending on a. What's the condition? Is it if the element in a is 5 (looking at your code)?

Comment: yes, if the element in a is 5, i want a corresponding value from b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is two dimensional, while it needs to have only one dimension. Try this:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if a[i] == 5:
            result.append(b[i])
    return np.asarray(result)
```

A nicer and more pythonic way do it will be like that:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    result = [b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if a[i] == 5]
    return np.asarray(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Note the way I made the b array is different than how you have it formatted up there. Basically, you just need an incrementer, in this case I used j. Then loop through a, and whenever a is equal to 5, append the corresponding b value to results

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([4,3,2,3,2,3,5])
b = np.array([-0.07, 0.08, -0.53, 0.25, 0.52, 0.11, 0.32])

def my_func(a,b):
    result = []
    j = 0
    for z in a:
        if z == 5:
            result.append(b[j])
        j += 1

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

For Numpy arrays, this is very simple:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([4,3,2,3,2,3,5])
>>> b = np.array([-0.07, 0.08, -0.53, 0.25, 0.52, 0.11, 0.32])
>>> b[ a==5 ]
array([ 0.32])
```